# TempData in controller is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have controller with TempData marked StatusMessage in it:

```
public class UsersController : Controller{
        [TempData]
        private string StatusMessage { get; set; }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> List()
        {
            ...
            Trace.WriteLine(StatusMessage);
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> MessageForList()
        {
            ...
            StatusMessage = "Some text";
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
}
```

When running this code StatusMessage reading receives null value, while expected is not null.

Answer (score -2):

TempData property should have `public` accessor:

```
[TempData]
public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
```